# React-Native / Typescript - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'react_1.default.Component)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Nothing related to PropTypes as I have seen dozens of problems related to that, my error refers directly to 'react_1.default.Component', undefined is not an object.

Has anyone hit this error? What files should I upload here?

```
import React from 'react';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import SideMenu from 'react-native-side-menu';

import Home from './app/screens/Home/Home';
import Menu from './app/components/Menu/Menu';

const Nav = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Map',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#ffffff'
    }
  }
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
        <Nav />
    );
  }
}
```

**Package.json** :

```
{
  "name": "Licenta2018",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "android": "react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-native": "^0.55.4",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.3",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.21.0",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: if you change your import for: `import * as React from 'react';`?

Comment: Can you also add the code for `Home` and `Menu` screens?, the given code is correct

Comment: Thanks, @rm4, I've tried many similar workarounds but not this one. It seems to work now.

Comment: @PritishVaidya those are working too, they were pretty much empty components with the same imports as App.js. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Great, you can add an answer below and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

for everyone wandering for an answer, this worked for me.
Worth a try!

Comment: Thanks! Keywords for others Googling: 
`(react_1.default.Component));` & `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Component')`